Is "If you want to master something, teach it." a Feynman quote?
Often, the quote

If you want to master something, teach it.

is attributed to Richard Feynman (for example, [1, 2, 3] and many more).
However, some claim the quote is attributed to Singh Yogi [5, 6] (the latter provide a source that is not available).
And although the quote makes sense to be attributed to Feynman as it fits his world view in my opinion, is there any evidence that this quote can be attributed to Richard Feynman?

Welcome to Skeptics! At the moment, you have provided evidence that a similar quote was made before Feynman, and evidence that Wikiquote users have found no evidence that it was said by Feynman. No-one is claiming it was said by Feynman. Can we find evidence that people are claiming it was said by Feynman? Otherwise we are tackling a claim no-one believes.

You know it was said earlier, so if Feynman did say it, so what? It can't be attributed to him.

Goodreads. Medium. Reddit. This article calls it the Feynman Technique but attributes it to Yogi Bhajan? UCL UG Math Colloquium...

It's all over the place.

@WeatherVane How do I know if the quote existed earlier?

@Schwern I agree. It's really hard to trace to find a reliable source.

@Oddthinking Lots of examples of people claiming this is from Feynman. How about reopening it?

@Schwern Thank you very much for the feedback and your efforts. I updated the questions according to your feedback and insights. Thanks again!

Did Feynman say it? Very likely. Was he the first person to say it? Very unlikely.

It is also here: https://x.com/ProfFeynman/status/1382902817153687555
